# Text field values not pass to another page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

**Page 1**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="geolocation()">

        <form method="GET" action="newjsp2.jsp">

         <input type ="text" id="loc1" name ="loc1" />
        <input type ="text" id ="lonandlat1" name ="lonandlat1"/>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
    <script>
          function geolocation(){



      function displayLocation(latitude,longitude){
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var method = 'GET';
        var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+latitude+','+longitude+'&sensor=true';
        var async = true;

        request.open(method, url, async);
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){
          if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
            var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            var address = data.results[0];
           // document.write(address.formatted_address);
             document.getElementById("loc1").value = address.formatted_address;
         //    alert(document.getElementById("loc1").value);
          }
        };
        request.send();
      };

      var successCallback = function(position){
        var x = position.coords.latitude;
        var y = position.coords.longitude;
        document.getElementById("lonandlat1").value=x+" "+y;
        displayLocation(x,y);
      };

      var errorCallback = function(error){
        var errorMessage = 'Unknown error';
        switch(error.code) {
          case 1:
            errorMessage = 'Permission denied';
            break;
          case 2:
            errorMessage = 'Position unavailable';
            break;
          case 3:
            errorMessage = 'Timeout';
            break;
        }
        document.write(errorMessage);
      };

      var options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 10000,
        maximumAge: 6000
      };
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback,errorCallback,options);


}

    </script>

</html>
```

**Page 2**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <input type ="text" id="loc1" value="<%  request.getParameter("loc1"); %>"/>

        <input type ="text" id="lonandlat1" value ="<%request.getParameter("lonandlat1");%>" />
    </body>
</html>
```

This is very small code of my project. Here in **page 1** first I am fetching current location that handle in `getlocation()` function of **javascript** and I called it into **onload** event of 1st page then after fetched I pass these values to next page that is **page 2** but I don't  know why values not passing to **page 2** ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, fetch the 'lonandlat1' via response above all the code you write in the **page2.jsp**.

```
        <%String var = request.getParameter("lonandlat1");%>
```

then replace :

```
        <input type ='text' id='lonandlat1' value ='<%request.getParameter('lonandlat1');%>' />
```

by

```
       <input type ='text' id='lonandlat1' value ='<%=var%>' />
```

Something like :

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%

    String var = request.getParameter("lonandlat1");
    String var2 = request.getParameter("loc1");

    %>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>

            <input type ="text" id="loc1" value="<%=var2%>"/>

            <input type ="text" id="lonandlat1" value ="<%=var%>" />
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out :

```
<%!
 String s;
%>

<%
s= request.getParameter("lonandlat1");
%>

<input type ="text" id="lonandlat" value ="<%out.print(s);%>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should divide your first page into two, you need data entered by clicking submit in the geolocation. Which you onload it, that means it will be called as soon as this page loads.

I'm not an expert but seem problematic for me.

Comment: Actually page 1 is running like background task in my project so can't add any clicking event in that page

Comment: but doesn't input type submit refers a submit button ?

Comment: Actually just give here a demo of my code I used submit button but indeed I won't used that